# Change Theme.AppCompat global color

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` for my activities. In standard this theme sets one color (green/blue hue) for all button text, dialog titles and stripes, check boxes, etc. I just need to change this base color to another. How can i do it?

For now I can only change accent color with:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/actis_app_green_accent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` (for dark theme) and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` (for light theme).

It will change the backgrounds and text color of some basic Views.

To to change specific view's colors you should add specific items inside theme block.
e.g.

```
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
```

Comment: Nope( The standard color haven't changed. As before, only colorAccent works with radioButtons color

Comment: You mean you want to do it dynamically ?

Comment: Nope - once and for all)

Comment: try changing to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`